# How to double click on an element using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is a dynamic list we have in our site.

[image: List Page]

This is the HTML tag where I want to pass double click on.

```
<td class="dxgv" align="left" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-size: 13px; border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(237, 237, 237); border-left-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; width: 5.6em; max-width: 6em; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">Sun Kumar</td>
```

I want to double click on the first record all the time even though first record gets deleted after each click

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since, you want to double click on the first record, you can try this java code:

**(Assuming there is one table in the webpage, as complete HTML code is not available above and the row for the contents starts with 2nd.)**

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.doubleClick(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr[2]//td[@class='dxgv'][1]"))).build().perform();
```

OR

```
 Actions act = new Actions(driver);
 act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr[2]//td[@class='dxgv'][1]"))).doubleClick().build().perform();
```

Comment: i will try it out and let you know

Comment: i have a doubt. For example if we have 'Save' button. After entering all the details and if i click on the 'Save' button, i want to verify that the particular field data isn't empty. I want to do that with 'if' loop...is it possible???

Comment: When you fill in the particular field, the attribute "value" of that field will change from null/empty to some data. So, you can get the attribute "value" from the field using "getAttribute("value")" and check if it is null/empty or not and then you can proceed clicking on the button accordingly

Comment: thanks subh. Do you know how to use if else loop in selenium webdriver. I try to use (if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//tr[2]//td[@class='dxgv'][1]) == null) but it showing error. how to use ifelse in webdriver

Comment: I suggest you post a different question in SO. you will get help from all.. Or else add me to a chat and we can continue from there. Actually elongating this conversation is not good as it is not associated with the question you've posted.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the double click does not work with the actions class you can use this proposal:

```
public void doubleClickWithJSExecutor(WebElement element) {
   JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   executor.executeScript("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('dblclick', { bubbles: true }));", element);
}
```