# click method is not working properly in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i am trying to Automate flipkart website in which i am trying to change address but "add new adress" is not getting clicked [i have attached the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4R7X.png)
my code is like `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ng-app']/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a/span")).click();`

please give the appropriate help

Comment: Is there an error? How can we reproduce this?

Comment: in eclipse it is not throwing any error that is the issue but befor this i tried to click many things and it worked but this part is not happening

Comment: Maybe the xpath is wrong?

Comment: no , xpath i have cross verified it is correct , you can verify from flipkart website.

Answer (score 1):

I doesn't look that you are clicking active element, the xpath is `//*[@id='ng-app']/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a/span` not correct it clicks on some span.

Use Firepath https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/ to get the xpath.

Comment: this xpath i got it from firepath only....and when i am trying to cross check it ...the correct target is getting highlighted

Comment: @user3388407 It is possible the test to be faster and might click before the element is visible or clickable. You can use Expected Conditions for waiting element to be visible and clickable. You have full documentation and examples here: https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that button is clickable Use `isDisplayed()` and `isEnabled()` method before clicking on "Add New Address" button, this method return boolean value.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ng-app']/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a/span")).isDisplayed();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ng-app']/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a/span")).isEnabled();
```

Also you can verify that element is exist on page or not using below code

```
if(driver.findElements(byVal).size()!=0){

// Element is present.

}
```

hope it may helpful to identify cause of issue, why its not clickable.

Comment: i have tried these commands, actually the button is displayed and is enabled also , when i am trying to click any of the button , it is not happening but the script dosen't throw any error , i tried for another button in same page like:-   `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ng-app']/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/a/p[4]/span")).click();` still it is not clicking, but manually i am able to click those things

Comment: i am not able to click anything through automation

Comment: try with  action api for clicking on element refer this link for clicking on element using action api. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054560/how-to-double-click-on-an-element-using-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

**First and foremost**, Use a customized Xpath instead of the one you are using which is extracted directly from the browser. If no customized Xpath can be constructed then try a customized Css or any other locator if possible.

Try to go through the following attempts in order (I hope you can grasp why this is):

1- If `.click()` still doesn’t work, then keep on changing the values of the attributes you are using to construct your customized xpath, cssSelector, or locator.

2- Use the Actions class.

3- Use JavaScript executioner

4- instead of `click()`, try using any of: `.sendKeys(“\n”).` Or `.sendKeys(keys.ENTER)` or `.sendKeys(keys.RETURN)`